# Python: Popen-ing command that expects a file, replace the file with a string?

Tags: python

I'm using python to run "drush scr" (drupal 7 command line) with Popen. Typical usage is "drush scr file.php", where file.php is a file containing php code. I use my python code to generate the php code as a string subsequently sent to file.php, and I don't want to have to create file.php just to then immediately send it to "drush scr file.php".

I've tried

```
sub=subprocess.Popen(['drush','scr'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE) 
ret=sub.communicate(input=createPHP())
```

where createPHP() creates the code that otherwise would be sent to file.php and then simply used as subprocess.Popen(['drush','scr','file.php']) to minimic command $drush scr file.php

```
def createPHP():
    #dynamically create php code as multi-line phpstring#
    return phpString    

sub=subprocess.Popen(['drush','scr'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE) 
ret=sub.communicate(input=createPHP())
print(ret)
```

This code throws an error from drush but also returns (None,None) from the print command.

The following code correctly executes the drush command:

```
f=open("file.php","w+")
f.write(createPHP())
f.close()
sub=subprocess.Popen(['drush','scr','file.php'])
ret=sub.communicate()
print(ret)
```

and returns (None,None). The latter code definitely works, but I would prefer to not be creating and closing files if possible, and I feel like I am just not using Popen correctly.

Comment: Just curious, what's the error message?

Comment: It's cut off but it's "Unable to find any of the following: /home/pi/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/&lt;, /var/www/drupal/scripts/venmo/&lt;                    [error]"
The script is in the /var/www/drupal/scripts/venmo/ directory. the /home/pi/.composer/vendor/bin/drush  is the drush executable location.